# $form->field radiio с разными атрибутами в группе чекбоксов

Tags: yii2

Как вывести  radiio  с помощью $form->field  с разными атрибутами

```
$form->field($model, 'radioButtonList')
->radioList([
    '1' => 'Первый',
    '2' => 'Второй',
    '3' => 'Третий'
]);
```

но что бы у '1' были одни атрибуты, а у '2' другие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$form->field($model, 'radioButtonList')
->radioList([
    '1' => 'Первый',
    '2' => 'Второй',
],
[
                                'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                                    if($value == 1){
                                        $className = "className1";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $className = "className2";
                                    }

                                    $return = '<label class="modal-radio">';
                                    $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" class="'.  $className  . '">';
                                    $return .= '<i></i>';
                                    $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                                    $return .= '</label>';

                                    return $return;
                                }
                            ]


);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'work_part_time')->radio(['label' => 'Option 1', 'value' => 1, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'work_part_time')->radio(['label' => 'Option 2', 'value' => 0, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'work_part_time')->radio(['label' => 'Option 3', 'value' => 2, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'work_part_time')->radio(['label' => 'Option 4', 'value' => 3, 'uncheck' => null]) ?>
```

И соответственно каждой радиокнопке сможете присвоить свои атрибуты

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но у меня при проверки проходит только Option 1, на остальные rules , думает что я не выбрал и выводит message поэтому я подумал что есть какое то решение для radioList